# SQL combinations

Tags: c#, sql

I have table that has multiple data for the same Id. I need to combinations on this data.

For example this the table contain

```
ID    Visit DAte       Visit number    Rational 
-----------------------------------------------
1     14/05/2011           1           new
1     15/06/2012           2           Emergency 
1     17/07/2012           3           Check-Up
```

up to 20 visit

The result that I want is like this

```
ID    Visit DAte       Visit number    Rational 
-------------------------------------------------
1     14/05/2011           1           new
1     15/06/2012           2           Emergency 
1     17/07/2012           3           Check-Up

1     14/05/2011           1           new
1     15/06/2012           2           Emergency 
1     19/07/2012           4           follwo-up

1     14/05/2011           1           new
1     15/06/2012           2           Emergency 
1     18/12/2012           5           Check-Up

etc....
```

The last one will be

```
1     14/01/2011           18          Referral 
1     15/02/2012           19          Check-up
1     18/10/2012           20          Emergency
```

Can I do this by query?

//-- I define a class and I define a list from that class

```
public struct ACVsize5
{
    public int ID;
    public DateTime date;
    public int RaId;
    public int HpId;
    public int DgId;
    public int VisitNum;
}

List<ACVsize5> patient = new List<ACVsize5>();
```

I used this quer but this select two value  but i need to get 3 or more

```
var query = patient.SelectMany((value, index) => patient.Skip(index + 1),
                          (first,second) => new { first, second });
```

//-- edit

I have to check the combination for one patient to match it with other 4 patients

I came up with generate the first combination if it is match i continue to generate the rest but this operation took long time process how i can increase the performance for the code below ?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {

            int id1 = getid(names[j].ToString(), 10000);

            for (int t = 0; t < 10000; t++)
            {
                generate_firstACV5A(id1, nvisit(id1), names[j].ToString());

                int id2 = getid(names[t].ToString(), 10000);
                if (id1 == id2) { }
                else
                {
                    generate_firstACV5B(id2, nvisit(id2), names[t].ToString());

if (comparefirst()==true)
                    {

if (count == 0)
                        {
                            safecount++;
                            if (safecount == 4) break;
                        }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here - how is the result set related to the original data?

Comment: The pattern I deduce here is `rows Choose 3` so for your example, you'll have 1140 sets.  Is that correct?

Comment: Also by "rational" do you mean "rationale"?  ... and by "feaver" do you mean "fever"?

Comment: yes it is correct the total will be 1140

Comment: It was my mistake for the rational part  I correct it on my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some example code that will generate sets of 3.  I don't know how an ORM will handle this if you let it handle the querying but if you have it locally as objects.

```
var queried = ... // example:  Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(n => new { FK = n });

var sets =
    from a in queried
    from b in queried
    from c in queried
    where a.FK < b.FK && b.FK < c.FK
    select new { a, b, c };
```

Using your code:

```
List<ACVsize5> patient = ... // filled by you but I assume a single unique ID

var sets =
    from a in patient
    from b in patient
    from c in patient
    where a.VisitNum < b.VisitNum && b.VisitNum < c.VisitNum
    select new {a, b, c}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Where I can put the table name on this query ?

Comment: @user1832754: You would query the data into a local data set (List, Array, any IEnumerable) and then edit the values in the LINQ statement to get your desired output.

Comment: Do you mean I load the data to Arraylist or list and then I use the given query on C# so then I got my result Right?

Comment: @user1832754:  Yes.  Except about the ArrayList -- there's little reason to use them past .Net 1.1..

Comment: I have create a class for my table and load the data on array from this class how I can use the above query on my array?

Comment: @Messi10:  You should experiment with the example query I included.

Comment: I have tried it but i do not know how  replace this ... on query

Comment: @Messi10:  You'll have to post some code (edit your question)

Comment: Austin Salonen it works well with me but i have an issue with select 5 from 65 visits the total will be 8259888 it takes 5 minutes to get this result Do you have an  idea to increase the performance ?

Comment: @Messi10:  `65 choose 5 == 8259888`.  At this point you may just want to query the VisitNums; run this query with just ints; and then requery for the full data.

Comment: one more question Austin I have 10000 records patients and every patient has there own visit on DB if i make the above combination i want to check the safety for the patient which mean the patient match 4 other patient combination to be safe  which is the best way to compute this  I made two for loop inside each other but this takes long time.

Comment: @Messi10:  Check out MSDN for Parallel.ForEach

Comment: I made a question related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617292/how-i-can-increase-c-sharp-performance-to-real-time