# How I can increase C# performance to real time

Tags: c#, sql

I have a huge amount of data that i need to compute it by C# 
I have 10000 patients on DB and every patient has an average 30 visits on his record on DB 
I need to check his combination for his visits which i have done it via LINQ [SQL combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554279/sql-combinations) in C#  and compare it with other patient 
if i found 4 other patients has the same combination i will consider it safe

I used this for loop code but take times  and I need to increase the performance

```
Parallel.For(0, 10000, (j,loopState) =>
        {
            int id1 = getid(names[j].ToString(), 101);
            Parallel.For(0, 10000, (t,loopState1) =>
                {
                    generate_firstACV5A(id1, nvisit(id1), names[j].ToString());
                    int id2 = getid(names[t].ToString(), 10000);
                    if (id1 == id2) { }
                    else
                    {
                        generate_firstACV5B(id2, nvisit(id2), names[t].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ACV5BFirst, ACV5Afirst) == true)
                    {
                        if (count == 0)
                     {
                         safecount++;
                         if (safecount == 4) {
                             ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(getid(names[j].ToString(), 1000).ToString());
                             it.SubItems.Add(names[j].ToString());
                             listView3.Items.Add(it); loopState1.Break();
                         }


                       }
                    }
                });
```

I got some run error when i compare the list to be true

I appreciate your help

Comment: do it in a stored proc. instead of RBAR ...?

Comment: How many list items you end up with when the code finishes?

Comment: I need to end up with to list one list for safe one for unsafe

Comment: And how many of those are there at the end, 1000, 100 or less? And do you have those patients in memory when executing this code?

Comment: I found some video that say stored procedure  does not increase the performance so i do not try this option

Comment: What error did you get?  Blanket statement like "stored procedure does not increase the performance" cannot always be true.  There will be some instances in which a stored procedure is faster, and others where it isn't.

Comment: 1000 patient is safe and the rest is not safe which is 9000

Comment: Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ACV5BFirst, ACV5Afirst) == true i got error on this line of code because the two list change many times during the for loop parallel

Comment: whats the ERROR MESSAGE?

Comment: Updating UI elements inside `Parallel.For`? There is no point to make this code fast because it is not correct! You can as well replace all of it with `throw new InvalidOperation("Accessing control on non-UI thread")`.

Comment: the list change many times something like that

Answer (score 2):

If you have at least few hundreds of the `ListViewItems` generated by your code, one of the problems is that you are adding `ListViewItems` during the code execution which triggers the `ListView` redrawing (which is slow compared to all other computing you have). Put your `ListViewItems` in the `List` first and when you finish, you add them as array, like this:

```
List<ListViewItems> list = new List<ListViewItems>();
Object myLock = new Object();
Parallel.For(0, 10000, (j,loopState) =>
        {
            int id1 = getid(names[j].ToString(), 101);
            Parallel.For(0, 10000, (t,loopState1) =>
                {
                    generate_firstACV5A(id1, nvisit(id1), names[j].ToString());
                    int id2 = getid(names[t].ToString(), 10000);
                    if (id1 == id2) { }
                    else
                    {
                        generate_firstACV5B(id2, nvisit(id2), names[t].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ACV5BFirst, ACV5Afirst) == true)
                    {
                        if (count == 0)
                     {
                         safecount++;
                         if (safecount == 4) {
                             ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(getid(names[j].ToString(), 1000).ToString());
                             it.SubItems.Add(names[j].ToString());

                             lock (myLock )
                             {
                                 list.Add(it); 
                             }

                             loopState1.Break();
                         }


                       }
                    }
                });
listView3.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

Even when locking the access to the list during Add will be much faster then redrawing the listView with approximately 1000 items. When I tested, this approach had been near 10 times faster.

Comment: Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ACV5BFirst, ACV5Afirst) == true )I got some error on this line of code the list is changed many times  during the for parallel loop operation

Comment: List.Add is not thread safe, and you will run into concurrency problems

Comment: I suppose you are using lists that are instantiated outside of the method and therefore other parallel loops are changing them. Create local lists ACV5BFirst and ACV5Afirst and then do compare on them.

Comment: @protector You are totally right, missed that, I'll edit

Comment: I would strongly recommend Messia to do this as a sproc. This type of grunt work is what SQL engines are built for - plus indexing, etc makes it a clear choice!

Comment: @protector How i can use store procedure  any suggest website methods

Comment: @ NikolaD - Nick my loop change the item of the list every time and compare it that is the purpose for the for loop  i need it to read the record and store it on a list and compare it because  I have 10000 patients so every time i compare two of them so the list is change it

Comment: and my list change in this method generate_firstACV5B(id2, nvisit(id2), names[t].ToString());
                    }